# icpx: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files

Tags: icc, nvcc

I can't seem to specify `-xRAPTORLAKE` to the intel compiler when also using nvcc.

```
nvcc -ccbin icpx -Xcompiler -xRAPTORLAKE -o exe_filename source_filename.cu
icpx: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
```

is there another way i can pass `-xRAPTORLAKE` to the intel compiler?